# Catching auto continuous focus start and finish events

Tags: android-camerax

I have created an app testing CameraX capabilities on my device. After setting up camera use cases auto continuous focus started automatically on PreviewView.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to catch auto continuous focus started and finished events? I want to put some animation on screen while auto continuous focus in progress as most of the device's pre-installed camera app does.
2. Is it possible to disable auto continuous focus feature? In some cases I want to allow only tap-to-focus feature enabled (which I have already implemented).